# Suse | keep account | Delete all user files at boot

Tags: user-accounts, suse

Can somebody explain me how i can keep an existing account on openSuse but delete all user files at the booting process?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the remove command to the `/etc/init.d/after.local` file:

`rm -rf /home/user/* /home/user/.*`

If the after.local file doesn't exist you can create it and it will still work. The system will recreate the files the first time you login afterward.